# ScrollView goes on top of another layout Android

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-imageview, android-scrollview

In the following code I've got two main containers, a RelativeLayout and a ScrollView. I need the RelativeLayout to be on top fixed and below that I need the ScrollView with Images to be scrollable. I've got the following two questions:

1. Though my ScrollView is scrollable but it goes on top of the RelativeLayout. !important
2. The view of my images present within the vertical LinearLayout are thumbnail sized. If I have 15-20 images, they take a lot of vertical space. How do I have the images to fit the maximum in a row based on the screen size and then go to the next row?

   ```
   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="vertical">
       </LinearLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>

   <ScrollView
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="vertical">

           <ImageView>
           </ImageView>

           <ImageView>
           </ImageView>

           <ImageView>
           </ImageView>

           <ImageView>
           </ImageView>

       </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these in simple way:

1. You need to use a fixed height for the parent, i.e., `<RelativeLayout>`.
2. Set the height of the `ScrollView` to `match_parent`.
3. Make sure you put everything inside a `LinearLayout`.

Finally you would end up with this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you can set your `RelativeLayout`'s height to a fixed value. Then  set your `ScrollView`'s height to `match_parent`, so it takes up all the available space. Then both of these should be contained in a vertical `LinearLayout`, to avoid any overlapping.